# How to pass a parameter name into a stored procedure with an optional param in asp

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, asp-classic

I am using a classic ASP application and the `ADODB.Recordset` and SQL Server.

When I am using a stored procedure:

```
command.Parameters.Append command.CreateParameter name:="name", value:="value"
```

size and direction too

the stored procedure I am using has an optional parameter.

So I only pass the param I need (the 3th and the 8th param only in this case)

I am getting an error, when I look with SQL Server profiler, I can see that the param has been passed without the param name (only the value)

And that the cause to the error

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You have to define all the parameters `.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("name", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50))` but you don't then have to pass a value if they are optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the command's property `NamedParameters = True` and prepend `@` character to each parameter's name. Taken from the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675840(v=vs.85).aspx):

> When this property is true, ADO passes the value of the Name property of each parameter in the Parameter collection for the Command Object. The provider uses a parameter name to match parameters in the CommandText or CommandStream properties. If this property is false (the default), parameter names are ignored and the provider uses the order of parameters to match values to parameters in the CommandText or CommandStream properties

Comment: I always had problems with `NamedParameters = True` in Classic ASP doesn't work with some providers.

Comment: @Lankymart You might be right, I have never encountered a problem however, in your solution the order of the parameters passed will be important.

Comment: @Dimt Not sure how that's a problem, but each to there own.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because of the way you are building the parameters, you must declare all parameters and append them to the parameters collection regardless of whether they will be executed.

```vb
With command
    'Declare all the parameters required or not in the order they 
    'should be applied and append them to the Parameters Collection.
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("name1", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("name2", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("name3", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50))
    .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("name4", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50))

    'Only define values for parameters you wish to pass.
    'In this case only "name2" and "name4" parameters are passed.
    .Parameters("name2").Value = "My Name 2 Value"
    .Parameters("name4").Value = "My Name 4 Value"
End With
```